# Is there a way to restrict a ssh key/user from accessing some part of the repo?

Tags: git, security, ssh, permissions, clone

I have a container running which is pulling a repository into its system. But I want to restrict its access to only one folder of that repository.

Say I have a repository my_code with two folders 
my_code/all 
my_code/restrict

The user with  should be able to pull only my_code/all and not my_code/restrict

Comment: I have never heard of this being done, but one possible solution might be to make the accessible portion of your codebase into a submodule, which is then part of the larger current repo.  Then, give access to only that submodule, to the user in question.

Comment: If the repository is hosted in a service like Github, Gitlab or Gerrit, you could also consider creating a branch which contains only the folder and giving the user access to only the branch.